# iOS sdk: how can I find if a link is download-able?

Tags: ios, download, nsurlconnection

Is there any way to get to know that a link is download-able? means the link represent any audio, video, zip etc.

I know I can do this by creating NSURLConnection and checking MIMETypes in its delegate. But I am looking for any other way because this method is not working well when URL is redirecting 2-3 times.

Please note that the workaround should also work on download links such as http://somewebsite.com/download.php?id=10293012983

Hope this question is clear. Please post comments if its unclear to anyone!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to contact the server the link points to, in order to get information about the link.

If you set the `HTTPMethod` on your request to `@"HEAD"`, then you'll just get the headers for whatever is hiding behind the link, without having to start a full download.

Answer (score 0):

check the response code 200=exists in method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
      NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
     NSLog(@"statusCode %d",[httpResponse statusCode]);
}
```

Comment: it will return 200 on every successful response, I want to detect only downloadable links, means audio, video, zip, rar, exe, msi etc.. which can not be open in UIWebView...